# Y Scale domain minimum / min NOT zero for stacked bar chart; overflowing X-Axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am very new to D3, and trying to figure out how to adjust my stacked bar chart when the domain is NOT [0, someMaxNumber]. I have tried a few different things, but to no avail.

I have tried...

1. `.attr("y", sequence => yScale(sequence[1] + yMin))` : This did actually make things fit in properly, but now my first data point did not start at 100 anymore, but now above it. That was incorrect so I did not stay there.
2. `.attr("height", sequence => { const [lower, upper] = sequence; return yScale(lower + yMin) - yScale(upper); })` : this fixed my previous problem (where things didn't start at the correct y-axis marks), but made the pink and green layer heights incorrect.

I also tried a bunch of other fixes, but I just can't get it to work. I swear it has to do with the height of the `rect` elements.

If you're wondering, my goal is to have the Y-Axis NOT start at 0, and instead start at some `min` such as 50% of the value of the smallest `rect` height. Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Changing point 2 above to the following code fixes my problem, but I think there should be a better solution for this. Please let me know.

```
.attr("height", (sequence, other, otherother) => {
   const [lower, upper] = sequence;
   const firstBarAdjustment = lower === 0 ? yMin : 0;
   return yScale(lower + firstBarAdjustment) - yScale(upper);
})
```

[image: Current image showing overflow]

```
class D3StackedBarChart extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    state: State = {
        data: [
            {year: 1993, males: 100, females: 95, pets: 12},
            {year: 1994, males: 80, females: 88, pets: 8},
            {year: 1995, males: 111, females: 122, pets: 32},
            {year: 1996, males: 25, females: 25, pets: 64},
            {year: 1997, males: 13, females: 45, pets: 72},
        ],
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const {data} = this.state;
        const keys = ["males", "females", "pets"];
        const colors = {
            males: "blue",
            females: "pink",
            pets: "green",
        };

        const width = 1000;
        const height = 1000;
        const margin = {top: 80, right: 180, bottom: 80, left: 180};
        // const margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0};
        const padding = 0.1;

        const stackGenerator = d3.stack().keys(keys); // now a function
        const layers = stackGenerator(data); // now a function

        // Origin of an SVG is in the TOP LEFT corner
        const svg = d3
            .select("#test")
            .append("svg") // append an svg element to our div#test
            .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
            .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
            .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

        // SCALE
        const xScale = d3
            .scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map(d => d.year))
            .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
            .padding(padding);

        // looking at second value / y value
        const extent = [
            0.5 *
                d3.min(layers, layer => d3.min(layer, sequence => sequence[1])),
            1.1 *
                d3.max(layers, layer => d3.max(layer, sequence => sequence[1])),
        ];
        const [yMin, yMax] = extent;

        const yScale = d3
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain(extent)
            .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]); // range from bottom up

        // AXIS
        const xAxis = g => {
            // bottom align it
            g.attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - margin.bottom})`)
                .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
                .attr("font-size", "20px");
        };

        const yAxis = g => {
            g.attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, 0)`)
                .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
                .attr("font-size", "20px");
        };

        // Create tooltip
        const Tooltip = d3
            .select("#test")
            .append("div")
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .attr("class", css(styles.tooltip))
            .style("background-color", "white")
            .style("border", "solid")
            .style("border-width", "2px")
            .style("border-radius", "5px")
            .style("padding", "5px");

        // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
        const mouseover = function(event, data) {
            Tooltip.style("opacity", 1);
            d3.select(this)
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("opacity", 1);
        };

        const mousemove = function(event, data) {
            const {0: start, 1: end, data: d} = data;

            Tooltip.html(`The year: ${d.year}<br> The value: ${end - start}`)
                .style("left", event.layerX + 3 + "px")
                .style("top", event.layerY - 3 + "px");
        };

        const mouseleave = function(event, data) {
            Tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
            d3.select(this)
                .style("stroke", "none")
                .style("opacity", 0.8);
        };

        // Creating Legend
        const legend = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("transform", d => "translate(0, 0)")
            .attr("font-size", "12px")
            .attr("text-anchor", "start")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(keys)
            .join("g") // Create 3 "g" elements that are initially empty
            .attr("transform", (d, i) => "translate(0," + i * 30 + ")");

        // Add square and their color
        legend
            .append("rect") // append a rect to each individual g
            .attr("fill", d => colors[d])
            .attr("x", width - margin.right)
            .attr("rx", 3)
            .attr("width", 19)
            .attr("height", 19);

        // Add text next to squares
        legend
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", width - margin.right + 40)
            .attr("y", 9.5)
            .attr("dy", "0.32em")
            .text(d => d);

        // Add header
        const legendHeader = d3
            .select(".legend")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", (d, i) => "translate(0, -20)")
            .lower()
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", width - margin.right)
            .attr("font-size", "12px")
            .text(() => {
                const text = "Master Levels";
                return text.toLocaleUpperCase();
            });

        // Get coordinates and height of legend to add border
        const {
            x: legendX,
            y: legendY,
            width: legendWidth,
            height: legendHeight,
        } = d3
            .select(".legend")
            .node()
            .getBBox();

        const borderPadding = 20;

        // Create border for legend
        // Adding a "border" manually
        const legendBox = svg
            .select(".legend")
            .append("rect")
            .lower()
            .attr("class", "legend-box")
            .attr("x", legendX - borderPadding)
            .attr("y", legendY - borderPadding)
            .attr("width", legendWidth + borderPadding * 2)
            .attr("height", legendHeight + borderPadding * 2)
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("opacity", 0.8);

        // Rendering
        // first, second, and third refer to `layers`
        // first --> layers
        // second --> edge1, edge2, and data
        svg.selectAll(".layer")
            .data(layers) // first
            .join("g") // create new element for each layer
            .attr("class", "layer")
            // .attr("class", css(styles.rectangle))
            .attr("fill", layer => colors[layer.key])
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(layer => layer) // second
            .join("rect")
            .attr("x", sequence => xScale(sequence.data.year))
            .attr("y", sequence => yScale(sequence[1]))
            .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", sequence => {
                const [lower, upper] = sequence;
                return yScale(lower) - yScale(upper);
            })
            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
            .on("mousemove", mousemove)
            .on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

        svg.append("g").call(xAxis);
        svg.append("g").call(yAxis);
        svg.node();
    }

    render(): React.Node {
        return (
            <View>
                <LabelLarge>{i18n.doNotTranslate("D3.js")}</LabelLarge>
                <Strut size={Spacing.xLarge_32} />
                <div id="test" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    tooltip: {
        position: "absolute",
    },
    rectangle: {
        ":hover": {
            opacity: 0.66,
        },
    },
});

export default D3StackedBarChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

`domain` of `yScale` should be in range from 0 to maximal sum of stack values:

```
const maxStackValue = data.reduce((m, d) => Math.max(m, keys.reduce((s, k) => s + d[k], 0)), 0);

const yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, maxStackValue])
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);
```

See it's working in the snippet:

```js
const data = [
  {year: 1993, males: 100, females: 95, pets: 12},
  {year: 1994, males: 80, females: 88, pets: 8},
  {year: 1995, males: 111, females: 122, pets: 32},
  {year: 1996, males: 25, females: 25, pets: 64},
  {year: 1997, males: 13, females: 45, pets: 72},
];

const keys = ["males", "females", "pets"];

const maxStackValue = data.reduce((m, d) => Math.max(m, keys.reduce((s, k) => s + d[k], 0)), 0);

const colors = {
  males: "blue",
  females: "pink",
  pets: "green",
};

const width = 1000;
const height = 1000;
const margin = {top: 80, right: 180, bottom: 80, left: 180};
// const margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0};
const padding = 0.1;

const stackGenerator = d3.stack().keys(keys); // now a function
const layers = stackGenerator(data); // now a function

// Origin of an SVG is in the TOP LEFT corner
const svg = d3
.select("#test")
.append("svg") // append an svg element to our div#test
.attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
.attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
.attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

// SCALE
const xScale = d3
.scaleBand()
.domain(data.map(d => d.year))
.range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
.padding(padding);


const yScale = d3
.scaleLinear()
.domain([0, maxStackValue])
.range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]); // range from bottom up

// AXIS
const xAxis = g => {
  // bottom align it
  g.attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
    .attr("font-size", "20px");
};

const yAxis = g => {
  g.attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, 0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
    .attr("font-size", "20px");
};


const mousemove = function(event, data) {
};

const mouseleave = function(event, data) {
};

// Creating Legend
const legend = svg
.append("g")
.attr("class", "legend")
.attr("transform", d => "translate(0, 0)")
.attr("font-size", "12px")
.attr("text-anchor", "start")
.selectAll("g")
.data(keys)
.join("g") // Create 3 "g" elements that are initially empty
.attr("transform", (d, i) => "translate(0," + i * 30 + ")");

// Add square and their color
legend
  .append("rect") // append a rect to each individual g
  .attr("fill", d => colors[d])
  .attr("x", width - margin.right)
  .attr("rx", 3)
  .attr("width", 19)
  .attr("height", 19);

// Add text next to squares
legend
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", width - margin.right + 40)
  .attr("y", 9.5)
  .attr("dy", "0.32em")
  .text(d => d);

// Add header
const legendHeader = d3
.select(".legend")
.append("g")
.attr("transform", (d, i) => "translate(0, -20)")
.lower()
.append("text")
.attr("x", width - margin.right)
.attr("font-size", "12px")
.text(() => {
  const text = "Master Levels";
  return text.toLocaleUpperCase();
});

// Get coordinates and height of legend to add border
const {
  x: legendX,
  y: legendY,
  width: legendWidth,
  height: legendHeight,
} = d3
.select(".legend")
.node()
.getBBox();

const borderPadding = 20;

// Create border for legend
// Adding a "border" manually
const legendBox = svg
.select(".legend")
.append("rect")
.lower()
.attr("class", "legend-box")
.attr("x", legendX - borderPadding)
.attr("y", legendY - borderPadding)
.attr("width", legendWidth + borderPadding * 2)
.attr("height", legendHeight + borderPadding * 2)
.attr("fill", "white")
.attr("stroke", "black")
.attr("opacity", 0.8);

// Rendering
// first, second, and third refer to `layers`
// first --> layers
// second --> edge1, edge2, and data
svg.selectAll(".layer")
  .data(layers) // first
  .join("g") // create new element for each layer
  .attr("class", "layer")
  .attr("fill", layer => colors[layer.key])
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(layer => layer) // second
  .join("rect")
  .attr("x", sequence => xScale(sequence.data.year))
  .attr("y", sequence => yScale(sequence[1]))
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", sequence => {
  const [lower, upper] = sequence;
  return (yScale(lower) - yScale(upper));
})
  .on("mousemove", mousemove)
  .on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

svg.append("g").call(xAxis);
svg.append("g").call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" />
```